# Не работает код на Python

Tags: python

```py
import os
import random

class game:    
    def ask():
        while True:
            global ask
            print('Камень Ножницы Бумага')
            print('[1] Камень')
            print('[2] Ножницы')
            print('[3] Бумага')
            ask = str(input('>> '))
    def ai():
        list = ['1', '2', '3']
        random.random(list)
    def logic():
        if random == '1' and ask == '1':
            def xx()
        if random == '1' and ask == '2':
            def lose()
        if random == '1' and ask == '3':
            def winner()
        if random == '2' and ask == '1':
            def winner()
        if random == '2' and ask == '2':
            def xx()
        if random == '2' and ask == '3':
            def lose()
        if random == '3' and ask == '1':
            def lose()
        if random == '3' and ask == '2':
            def winner()
        if random == '3' and ask == '3':
            def xx()
    def winner():
        print('Ты выиграл!!!!')
        print(\n)
        print('Повторим?')
        print('[1] Да')
        print('[2] Нет')
        ask = str(input('>> '))
        if ask == '1':
            def ask()
        if ask == '2':
            os.exit()
    def lose():
        print('Ты проиграл :(')
        print(\n)
        print('Повторим?')
        print('[1] Да')
        print('[2] Нет')
        ask = str(input('>> '))
        if ask == '1':
            def ask()
        if ask == '2':
            os.exit()
    def xx():
        print('Ничья -_-')
        print('Переигрываем...')
        def logic()


game.ask()
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(), main.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 18
    def xx()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: что не работает? как не рабоает? в какой стоке какая ошибка?

Comment: Код отлично работает - исполняет ровно то что написано ...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 18
    def xx()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]

Comment: сверху текст ошибки

Comment: все внутрь вопроса. кнопочка "править" вам в помощь

Comment: @splash58 исправил

Comment: `if random == '1' and ask == '1': def xx()` вот тут вы что хотели? вызвать функция? тогда def не нужен

Comment: Читабельность кода подтяните, вам самим приятно такой бред читать?

Comment: def logic() - тоже не понятно

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import random

while True:
    print('Камень Ножницы Бумага\n', '[0] Выход\n', '[1] Камень\n', '[2] Ножницы\n', '[3] Бумага\n')

    ask = int(input('Ответ: '))
    rand = random.randint(1, 3)

    if ask == 0:
        sys.exit()
    elif rand == ask:
        print('Ничья -_-', 'Переигрываем...\n')
    elif (rand, ask) in [(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)]:
        print('Ты выиграл!!!!\n')
    elif (rand, ask) in [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)]:
        print('Ты проиграл :(\n')
    else:
        print('Ответ должен быть от 1 до 3\n')
```

Comment: Вместо `elif rand == 1 and ask == 3 or rand == 2 and ask == 1 or rand == 3 and ask == 2:`  может выть `elif (rand, ask) in ((1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)):`

Comment: @MarianD отличное дополнение, благодарю! Поправил

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, не нужно использовать класс:

1. Удалите из начала вашей программы строку `class game:`,
2. удалите отступы связанные с этим определением в последовательных строках,
3. в последней строке вместо `game.ask()` используйте только `ask()`.

---

Главная ошибка, что вы путаете

- **определение функции** (например `def lose():`)
- с ее **применением** (вызовом, напр. `lose()`, т.е. без ключевого слова `def` в начале и без двоеточия в конце).

Функция *определяется (обычно) только один* раз и в Питоне нужно ее определить *перед ее первым вызовом (применением).*

Значит:

1. все 3 *определения функций* в конце программы переместите в начало,
2. дальше эти функции уже только вызывайте, т.е. в виде `winner()`, `lose()` и `xx()` (без `def` и двоеточия).
3. тоже другие функции (определенные в начале программы) вызывайте без `def` и двоеточия.

---

Дальше:

1. Имя `ask` вы используете как имя **функции**, так и как имя переменной для хранения пользователем введенной **строки**. Ожидайте последствие в виде чудесных ошибок, или примените разные имена.
2. То же самое для имени `random` - `import random` в начале программы определяет `random` как имя **модуля**, и вы, наверно, хотели (но не сделали, см. пункт 4 ниже) использовать его для хранения случайного **числа**.
3. Не надо применить функцию `str()` в командах `ask = str(input('>> '))`, т.к. функция `input()` всегда возвращает строку (т.е. тип `str`). Достаточно `ask = input('>> ')`.
4. Функцию `ai()` вы определили, но никогда не применили. Вы, наверно, хотели применить ее после того, что пользователь выбрал 1, 2 или 3.